# Creating Custom Springboard and link to pages

Tags: java, xml, mobile, oracle-maf, springboard

I have created springboard on oracle maf which linked into AMX pages. I have followed the following link :https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_spring/tut_jdev_maf_spring.html

However, I can't go into another link from Springboard menu . The first page is repeatedly coming up. I have found other developers are facing this issue as below link :
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3650470 
I tried to follow his solution as well. But, I  passed  #{pageFlowScope.FeatureId} in the bindings of gotofeature.

Here is my code of Springboard.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<amx:view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:amx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx"
          xmlns:dvtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx/dvt">
  <amx:panelPage id="pp1">
    <amx:facet name="header">
      <amx:tableLayout id="tl1" halign="center">
        <amx:rowLayout id="rl1">
          <amx:cellFormat id="cf5" >
            <amx:outputText value="Care Apps" id="ot1" styleClass="titleText" />
          </amx:cellFormat>
        </amx:rowLayout>
      </amx:tableLayout>
    </amx:facet>
    <amx:facet name="primary">
        <amx:tableLayout id="tl2" halign="center">
        <amx:rowLayout id="rl2">
                <amx:cellFormat id="cf4" >
            <amx:image id="i3" source="/images/CARE_logo_60.png"/>
          </amx:cellFormat>
        </amx:rowLayout>
        </amx:tableLayout>
    </amx:facet>
    <amx:tableLayout id="tl4" styleClass="menuUserLayout">
      <amx:rowLayout id="rl6">
        <amx:cellFormat id="cf6" halign="center" valign="middle">
          <amx:image id="i4" source="/images/user_logo.png" inlineStyle="width:100px; height:100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
        </amx:cellFormat>
      </amx:rowLayout>
      <amx:rowLayout id="rl5">
        <amx:cellFormat id="cf3">
          <amx:outputText value="User Name" id="ot3" styleClass="menuText"/>
        </amx:cellFormat>
      </amx:rowLayout>
    </amx:tableLayout>
    <amx:tableLayout id="tl3" styleClass="menuTabLayout">
      <amx:iterator var="row" value="#{bindings.features.collectionModel}" id="i1" >
        <amx:rowLayout id="rl3">
          <amx:cellFormat id="cf1">
            <amx:commandLink actionListener="#{bindings.gotoFeature.execute}"
                             disabled="#{!bindings.gotoFeature.enabled}" id="cl1">
              <amx:image id="i2" source="#{row.image}" inlineStyle="width:45px;height:45px;"/>
              <amx:setPropertyListener id="spl1" from="#{row.id}" to="#{pageFlowScope.FeatureId}" type="action"/>
            </amx:commandLink>
          </amx:cellFormat>
          <amx:cellFormat id="cf2">
            <amx:outputText value="#{row.name}" id="ot2" styleClass="menuText"/>
          </amx:cellFormat>         
        </amx:rowLayout>
        <amx:rowLayout id="rl4">       
        </amx:rowLayout>
      </amx:iterator>
    </amx:tableLayout>
  </amx:panelPage>
</amx:view>
```

The menu link is not working though.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution. I changed to InstanceName="data.ApplicationFeatures.dataProvider" from InstanceName="bindings.gotoFeature.dataControl.dataProvider" in methodAction on SpringboardPageDef.xml.

Finally, the link works. :)